# My computer detects all flash drives as HDD

Tags: windows

I noticed this problem when i made easy app that showed all disk drives, hdd etc.
All my pendrives were detected as HDD.
They are ntfs. I tried with FAT but it still shown as hdd.

Some time after that i had to reinstall windows because of some problems. I couldn't find the pendrive in boot order. There was only CDROM and HDD. I went to something like "HDD BOOT PRIORITY" and there was my pendrive.
Can someone tel me why its like that?

Comment: Umm, because flash drives emulate HDDs (i.e. they have a partition table).  Why is that a problem for you?

Comment: on other pc's they were detected as Removable Devices on BIOS and in my program too